# c++ custom iterator constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, iterator

The following code prints the numbers from 0 to 9 with custom iterators. I compile with `g++ -std=c++11 -o test test.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>

class some_class;

class some_class_iterator : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, int>{   private:    
    friend class some_class;
    int pointed;
    some_class_iterator(int _pointed): pointed(_pointed){
        std::cout << "over here" << std::endl;
    }

public: 
    int poitned;

    int operator*(){
        return pointed;
    }

    const some_class_iterator& operator++(){
        pointed++;
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator!=(const some_class_iterator& other) const {
        return this->pointed != other.pointed;
    }   

};

class some_class{
public:
    typedef some_class_iterator iterator;

    iterator begin(){
        return some_class_iterator(0);  
    }

    iterator end(){
        return some_class_iterator(10);
    }

};


int main(){

    some_class a;
    for (some_class::iterator i = a.begin(); i != a.end(); ++i) std::cout << *i << std::endl;   

}
```

However, the output is not what i expected to be as `over here` is printed multiple times. 
For example actual output is :

```
over here
over here
0
over here
1
over here
2
over here
3
over here
4
over here
5
over here
6
over here
7
over here
8
over here
9
over here
```

So who is causing the call on the constructor here?

My actual problem is on a binary search tree iterator where in the constructor i create a FIFO traversal with the nodes to be printed depending on (in, pre, post), so calling the constructor multiple times is costy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every iteration of your loop you call `a.end()`, which will create a new iterator and print "over here".  You could print out the value of `_pointed` to see this.  (The first "over here" is from the `begin` call).

Comment: *High five!* ... and some filler text.

Comment: @k_kaz Nah, you got some inspiration for future debugging techniques out of it, so it's kind of a win in the end.

Answer (score 2):

Every time you check the condition in your for loop, you call end(), which constructs a new iterator.

If you add pointed_ to your debug output, it can help trace things like that. So can adding printouts to your other calls, and also stepping through in a debugger.

To avoid it you could cache end before the for loop but that's weird and doesn't fit the usual pattern for looping with iterators. A better solution could be to store end as a member in your class and have end() return a reference to it, or see if you can find a way to make iterator construction less costly in your real program.

Comment: If some_class::end() returned this const reference you speak of, whould that be a better design?